# Loss of precision on decimal, possible formatting issue? C programming language

Tags: c, decimal

I have an assignment that requires us to calculate pi by determining whether or not a point is inside a circle or outside it.

I have the assignment done, and it works great - except my answer is always rounded after the 3rd decimal point. Other classmates have precision up to 6 decimal points, and I'd like to know where I'm going wrong. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
  int square = 10; //this is the size of the square that contains the circle
  int points = 1000; //this is how many points to test (how many times to run the loop)
  double randX;
  double randY;
  int insideCircle = 0;
  int outsideCircle = 0;
  srand(time(NULL));

  double radius = square / 2.0;
  for (int i = 0; i < points; i++) {
    randX = ((double)rand())/RAND_MAX * square;
    randY = ((double)rand())/RAND_MAX * square;

    if (( (pow(randX - radius,2.0)) + (pow(randY - radius,2.0))) < pow(radius,2.0)) {
      insideCircle++;
    } else {
      outsideCircle++;
    }

  }

  double pi = 4.0 * (double)insideCircle / (double)points;

  printf("\n\nPi: %lf", pi);
  return 0;
}
```

I assume my error lies in the formatting of my last print statement, but I can't seem to nail it down!

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The full source helps, especially when it is this short.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify 6 decimal places like this

```
printf("\n\nPi: %.6lf", pi);
```

Although as @clcto commented, that is the default.

Perhaps the rounding of 3 decimal places is because 1000 points are tested.

Comment: But by default it should be 6. ["For a, A, e, E, f and F specifiers: this is the number of digits to be printed after the decimal point (by default, this is 6)."](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/)

Comment: @clcto I was just coming to that - the fault must lie in the algorithm.

Comment: I had a little look at this just to get a feel for what's required to get the world record. If I used say 9 decimal places in my algorithm then the result was only accurate to say 6 digits.

Comment: This was the answer. It only was 3 decimal places because so few points were tested.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing is going wrong here. You are sampling 1000 points chosen at random and then calculating π with the following formula:

```
double pi = 4.0 * (double)insideCircle / (double)points;
```

Since `points` is equal to 1000, you will get a result with three places of decimals.